# Switch construct in a static method

Tags: java, interface, switch-statement

i have this problem:
I am making a functional interface that converts DAYS into LESSONS, both DAYS and LESSONS  are enum types.
What I want to achieve is an interface with two methods:
One STATIC method will take as input a DAY enum and returns a LESSON.
Another method which is abstract, will parse a set of Days and return a set of Lessons.

The problem lies with the first method, I've implemented it as such:

```
public interface Converter {
    static Lessons inputConverter(Days input) {
        switch (input) {
        case MONDAY:
            return Lessons.HISTORY;
        case SUNDAY:
            return Lessons.MATH;
        default:
            return Lessons.HISTORY;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to use it:

```
Converter.inputConverter(Days.MONDAY);
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   Update to static final field Converter.$SWITCH_TABLE$Days attempted
>   from a different method ($SWITCH_TABLE$Days) than the initializer
>   method

If i use an IF/ELSE statement there is no error, so I figured that the problem lies in the switch, but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong since I'm not trying to modify any field.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals this: https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8190783, which seems superficially relevant.

Comment: It's also probably better to *actually* implement a functional interface and to have a singleton instance rather than making things static.

Comment: @Tsurupeta,
Have you resolved this issue.? I'm facing this now and please double check with other IDE's. for me its works in intellJ and not works in eclipse

Comment: bug link updated >> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8190783