# Why eclipse IDE is giving this error when running Gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, cxf, java-17

The project is using Gradle as a build tool.

- java version is openjdk-17.0.1
- eclipse version is  2022-09 (4.25.0)
- gradle version is gradle-7.3

For this situation, I've tried to make a similar small java application but couldn't reproduce the issue
but I saw this related bug >> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8190783

Also, another issue that I noted is eclipse classes created in **bin folder**
but gradle generated classes stay in **build folder**

In the build folder, I saw BaseInterface.class and BaseInterface$1.class
but in the bin folder only I can see BaseInterface.class

It seems this issue is similar to my issue, but couldn't find a solution for that as well
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618143/switch-construct-in-a-static-method](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/49618143/switch-construct-in-a-static-method)
Please advise.

Here are some code samples from the project.
First, there is an interface with a static switch instantiation scenario

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    static BaseInterface getCardType(CardType cardType) {
        if (cardType == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR BECAUSE NULL");
        }
        switch (cardType) {
        case CREDIT:
            return new CreditCardImpl();
        case DEBIT:
            return new DebitCardImpl();
        case VISA:
            return new VisaCardImpl();
        case MASTER:
            return new MasterCardImpl();

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("NOT SUPPORT");
        }
    }
    public void getMessage();
}
```

Here is the enum

```
public enum CardType {

    CREDIT("Credit Card"), DEBIT("Debit Card"), MASTER("Master Card"), VISA("Visa Card");

    private String type;

    private CardType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

And some implementations for baseInterface

```
public class CreditCardImpl implements BaseInterface {
    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Credit Card Impl");
    }
}
```

Finally here is the main method included application class

```
public class CardTypeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseInterface cardTypeImpl=BaseInterface.getCardType(CardType.CREDIT);
        cardTypeImpl.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This application build success and gave successful outcomes.
But in same scenario give the below error

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Update to static final field com.gradletester.BaseInterface.$SWITCH_TABLE$com$gradletester$CardType attempted from a different method ($SWITCH_TABLE$com$gradletester$$CardType) than the initializer method <clinit> 
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) [jetty-server-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) [jetty-io-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) [jetty-util-9.4.12.v20180830.jar:9.4.12.v20180830]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Update to static final field com.gradletester.BaseInterface.$SWITCH_TABLE$com$gradletester$CardType attempted from a different method ($SWITCH_TABLE$com$gradletester$CardType) than the initializer method <clinit> 
    at com.gradletester.BaseInterface.$SWITCH_TABLE$com$gradletester$CardType(BaseInterface.java:4) ~[main/:?]
```